# Excel formula - if one cell equals another then add

Tags: excel-formula

Example

```
A-------B------C------D 

20------?------75-----2

22------?------23-----3

23------?------25-----5

24------?------20-----1

50------?------36-----2

36------?------22-----4

75------?------12-----1
```

If cell 1(75) from column C searches column A, if it finds 75 then enter column D cell 1(2) into column B cell 1.

Repeat until column C is finished.

Please forgive me, I've never done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

> =IF(VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$A$7,1,FALSE),D1)

paste that formula into b1 thru b7 and it should update references

[image]

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$A$7,1,FALSE),D1)),"",IF(VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$A$7,1,FALSE),D1))` would remove the annoying #N/A error

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
That worked very well,but the numbers in column D are not going to the right place in column B.
Example:the first cell in column D is 2 that should go in column B next to 75 of column A and so on.

Comment: @user3033823 Then you should also update your question because it quite clearly states that the matched D1(2) value should go into B1... when the information from your comment above now says it should go into B7.

Comment: Timfoden you are 100% correct,I'm sorry, the latter is the correct question. Please, if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, given your comment about the 2 next to 75 from column D needs to go int column B to the right of the 75, and also incorporating error checking code from Pankaj, try this one:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$D$7,2,FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$D$7,2,FALSE))
```